# Mysql ordering for which satisfy multipe condtion

Tags: mysql

Please see the result field->dep_fields in the image.

The dep_fields which has value **11,29** should come first as it satisfy the multiple condition FIND_IN_SET(11,`dep_fields`),FIND_IN_SET(29,`dep_fields`)

and

**29** in second order it satisfy only one condition FIND_IN_SET(29,`dep_fields`).

I need the ordering, which satisfy more where clause condition for the field dep_fields.

```
  SELECT * FROM mascot_question
   WHERE `dependent` = 8 
   AND (
   FIND_IN_SET(11,`dep_fields`) 
   OR FIND_IN_SET(14,`dep_fields`) 
   OR FIND_IN_SET(16,`dep_fields`) 
   OR FIND_IN_SET(26,`dep_fields`) 
   OR FIND_IN_SET(29,`dep_fields`) 
   OR `dep_fields` = ""
   );
```

[image]

I need the ordering, which satisfy more where clause condition for the field dep_fields. (aka, sort by most matched in FIND_IN_SET)

Comment: Your question is not clear as to what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: I need the ordering for which a fields satisfy more number of where condition.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
ORDER BY 
   IF(FIND_IN_SET(11,`dep_fields`), 1, 0)
   + IF(FIND_IN_SET(14,`dep_fields`), 1, 0)
   + IF(FIND_IN_SET(16,`dep_fields`), 1, 0)
   + IF(FIND_IN_SET(26,`dep_fields`), 1, 0)
   + IF(FIND_IN_SET(29,`dep_fields`), 1, 0) DESC
```

This will add `1` for each match, and order by the total.

You should also reconsider using a comma-separated list in a table field. It's better to normalize this with a many-to-many relationship table. This makes matching the fields more efficient (`FIND_IN_SET` can't make use of indexes), and you can use `COUNT(*)` to count the number of matches and order by it.

Comment: according to the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) find_in_set returns the index of the item in the list. It's not a boolean function

Comment: Oops, forgot that. I've fixed it to use `IF` to normalize them to boolean values.

Comment: Yes, the table content is small  so i didn't used n-n relation in this. Thank you very much... :)